# Running scripts on google cloud sdk shell?

Tags: shell, batch-file, google-bigquery, gcloud

I have to run mutiple gsutil and bq commands in google cloud sdk shell.I tried to create a cmd file file and write allcommands in it but it is running only the first command of that file.Can i do that on google cloud sdk shell?

Comment: Sounds to me you typed something wrong. Show us how you wrote the commands in the file.

Comment: gsutil ls
gsutil -m cp -r C:\Users\adarsh.srivastava\Desktop\REmFIles\* gs://bqcommand_week2

Comment: above commands i wrote in batch file and tried to run it but it is running only gsutil ls but not the command after that.

Comment: for cmd file in google cloud sdk shell i did echo gsutil ls >> test.cmd and then echo bq query "query_string which i wanted to run" >> test.cmd  and then i run test.cmd it was running only the first command....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I run 2 commands consecutively using batch file for gcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185889/why-cant-i-run-2-commands-consecutively-using-batch-file-for-gcloud)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `CALL` before each command, for example:

```
CALL gcloud app deploy
CALL gcloud app describe
```