# How to authenticate to GCP for command line uploads

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have created a service account and I can authenticate with a

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <json file>
```

and I have successfully executed the gsutil rsync command to upload files.  The issue is that the gcloud auth command appears to terminate the batch file and the following gsutil rsync commands do not execute.  How should the batch file be setup to allow the authentication followed by the rsync commands and then a final auth revoke?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I run 2 commands consecutively using batch file for gcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185889/why-cant-i-run-2-commands-consecutively-using-batch-file-for-gcloud)

Comment: Thanks!  I searched for a similar question, but I guess I did not use the right terms.  I had actually just started another test using the call option.